# Webscraping in R, accessing html nodes

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

A straightforward application of the `rvest` package: I'm trying to scrape a class of html links from a site.

This code gives me what looks like the right nodes from a site:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

foo <- "http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2010/house/2010_elections_house_map.html" %>% 
            read_html
```

Separately, I located the right nodes using a css selector:

```
foo %>% 
  html_nodes("#states td") %>% 
  extract(2:4)
```

which returns

```
{xml_nodeset (3)}
[1] <td>\n  <a class="dem" href="/epolls/2010/house/ar/arkansas_4th_district_rankin_vs_ross-1343.html">\n    <span>AR4</span>\n  </a>\n</td>
[2] <td>\n  <a class="dem" href="/epolls/2010/house/ct/connecticut_1st_district_brickley_vs_larson-1713.html">\n    <span>CT1</span>\n  </a>\n</td>
[3] <td>\n  <a class="dem" href="/epolls/2010/house/ct/connecticut_2nd_district_peckinpaugh_vs_courtney-1715.html">\n    <span>CT2</span>\n  </a>\n</td>
```

Ok, so the `href` attribute is what I'm looking for. But this

```
foo %>% 
  html_nodes("#states td") %>% 
  extract(2:4) %>% 
  html_attr("href")
```

returns

```
[1] NA NA NA
```

How can I access the underlying links?

Comment: try `foo %>%  html_nodes("#states td a") %>%  extract(2:4) %>% html_attr("href")`

Comment: @jay you should make that an answer. tomw: you aren't targeting the anchor and Jay's solution does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xml_children()`, you could do:

```
foo %>% 
  html_nodes('#states td') %>% 
  xml_children %>%
  html_attr('href') %>%
  extract(2:4)
```

Returns:

```
[1] "/epolls/2010/house/ar/arkansas_4th_district_rankin_vs_ross-1343.html"            
[2] "/epolls/2010/house/ct/connecticut_1st_district_brickley_vs_larson-1713.html"     
[3] "/epolls/2010/house/ct/connecticut_2nd_district_peckinpaugh_vs_courtney-1715.html"
```

You could put `extract` in front of `html_attr`, and possibly some other sequences might work too.